# How to create time property that is always 24 hours behind current time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a time object, which I use to gather all info from the past 24 hours, I have no issue creating the object displaying the current time. But I am unsure as to how to set it exactly 24 hours in the past, without having the timezone attached.

```
  def set_time
     @past_time = Time.now.to_s(:db) - 1.days
  end
```

Expected Output Format :

```
 "2021-11-29 09:15:17"
```

Result:

```
 undefined method `-' for "2021-11-29 10:19:46":String
```

Comment: When there should be no timezone information attached what timezone to use then? The server's timezone that might be in UTC or any other timezone or your local timezone?

Comment: Note that by default, Rails converts timestamps to UTC when saving them to the database and back to localtime when reading them from the database. So if you're going to use that time object just for queries, you might re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

You are subtracting the time from the string object as you converted `Time.now` into the string using `to_s`.

Instead of you can do this

```
(Time.new - 1.days).to_s(:db)
```

Note: You will get multiple ways to accomplish these rails. You can improve the code readability and understanding of code by doing this.

Example:

```
DateTime.now.days_ago(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest I can think of would be:

```
24.hours.ago.to_s(:db)
```

Note that the returned time would default to UTC in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DateTime#advance`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-advance) from ActiveSupport:

```
Time.current.advance(hours: -24)
# or 
Time.current.advance(days: -1)
```

Note that in timezones that use DST a day is not always 24 hours so the two are not actually equivilent. You can also use the methods that [ActiveSupport::Duration](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html) monkeypatches onto Integer:

```
24.hours.ago
1.day.ago
```

This always uses your default timezone though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, all of the above return a time zone attachment ie  CET +01:00. Whereas I'm using this in a specific query param for an API that does not accept the declaration of a time zone.

Comment: Use `Time.now.utc` or `Time.now.in_time_zone(timezone)` if you don't want to use the time zone of your app. Even if the API doesn't declare a time zone you still need to decide what timezone you're actually going to treat the times as.